# HttpPostedFile in File Upload process is NULL if I use AJAX

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax, file-upload

I am using file upload functionality in my asp.net MVC project.
It worked great until I started using some AJAX functionality on my page.

The HttpPostedFile is always NULL on Ajax page.

How can solve this issue along with calling ajax on my page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you cannot upload files using AJAX I would recommend you the excellent [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) which allows you to ajaxify your forms and supports [file uploads](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#file-upload). Behind the scenes the plugin generates a hidden iframe to handle the upload and is completely transparent to you:

```
<form id="myForm" action="/home/upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="upload" />
</form>
```

Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    // TODO: handle the file here
    return PartialView("success");
}
```

And finally ajaxify the form:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myForm').ajaxForm(function(result) {
        alert('thank you for uploading');
    });
});
```

Also notice the usage of [`HttpPostedFileBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase.aspx) instead of [`HttpPostedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfile.aspx) in the controller action. Being an abstract class this will simplify your unit tests.

Comment: Hi can you help me out with a solution to mine also, on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28695630/how-do-i-upload-an-image-using-jquery-file-input-control-with-my-asp-net-web-ser/28696192#28696192

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to post a file upload using ajax unless you jump through some hoops - such as posting a sub from from within an IFrame, or by using one of the Flash based solutions.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254831/asp-net-free-ajax-file-upload-control

Answer (score 0):

XHR can not file post.

Asnc file upload use iframe or some library.